# Unable to dual boot ubuntu alongside windows 10/11

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi, acer

Laptop: Acer Nitro 5

System Details

1. CPU: AMD Ryzen 5600H
2. GPU: RTX 3060

BIOS Details

1. UEFI (unchangable)
2. SATA: AHCI (unchangable)

Before I attempt to dual boot:

1. I enable F12 boot
2. I disable Fastboot (however it automatically gets enabled after reboot)
3. I disable secure boot

The live usb works, and the entire installation process works. But it freezes at the acer logo after rebooting. I tried the tricks to disable nouveau. No success.

I also tried installing ubuntu without any internet connection. I was able to boot in without a problem, until I update and upgrade packages. After that, I am stuck again at Acer logo.

Are there any other tricks left?

Comment: You need to either enable the installation of drivers while installing Ubuntu or install the Nvidia drivers later.

Comment: Many need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. Some older Acer also needed "trust" setting in UEFI. Acer Nitro 7 Missing AHCI mode Ctrl + S in UEFI
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2429951&p=13900969#post13900969
Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 Acer Aspire 5 Model A515-54-5649  Intel Core i5-10210U Install Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2437702

Comment: @ChanganAuto "enable the installation of drivers while installing Ubuntu" Doesn't that happen already when we tick the "third party" drivers. I tried that but that's what's casugint the problem I think. And I didn't even install the nvidia drivers. Did you mean something else?

Comment: No, I meant exactly that. Please read the comment from oldfred above and all the links.

Comment: I will. thanks.